# Is this python code dangerous?

Tags: python, combinations

I really want to know what would happen if this python script executed, but I'm afraid something bad might happen if I do it.  Does anyone know what actually would happen?

```
import itertools
import pickle
x = list(itertools.combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',4))
y = []
for i in x:
    pickle.dump(y, open(str(i) + ".py","wb"))
```

Comment: Run it and see what happens

Comment: You can always CTRL-C if it takes too long, but there is nothing *dangerous* in that code.

Comment: It will most likely throw a `NameError` exception as `wb` variable is not defined.

Comment: Run, and go take some coffee...

Comment: Marciej Gol isn't wb "write binary"?

Comment: If you wanted to set it as write binary, you must do this "wb"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the syntax error fixed:

```
import itertools
import pickle
x = list(itertools.combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',4))
y = []
for i in x:
    pickle.dump(y, open(str(i) + ".py","wb"))  # quotes around wb
```

... it creates about sixty-thousand files with silly names in the current working directory, all with the same content – a small, easily recreated representation of an empty list – in about five seconds on my machine (and twenty seconds the second time, as it has to overwrite the files).

Comment: that's what I was guessing it would do, but I'm curious, did it cause any runtime errors or take up much space on the hard drive?  I feel like sixty-thousand files is a lot...

Comment: 700MB - whether that's a lot depends on the context, really.

Comment: does that mean that if "y" was filled with data, it would take up multiplicatively more?  And on another note, how did you end up getting rid of that many useless files?

Comment: If there was a lot more data, yes - even tiny files take up significant space on the disk due to the way the filesystem works. And I ran it in its own folder, so `cd .. ; rm -rf my_working_folder`